# redirect to page depending on the url

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pull in the url (including path) and set it to a variable with jQuery, read the variable and see if it matches anything.

I can see it work because I can see the outputs in the console, but the body won't change colour.

NOTE: Yes, I have opened the file with my file called `facebook.php` (so the background should go blue)

My code is below:

```
function containsStrURL() {
    console.info("redirect.jm.js: Started!");


    var str = window.location.pathname;

    var res = str.match(/facebook/g);
    if (res === "facebook") {
        $(document.body).css({
            'background-color': '#3E5B98'
        });
    } else {
        res = srt.match(/twitter/g);
        if (res === "twitter") {
            $(document.body).css({
                'background-color': '#4DA7DE'
            });
        }
    }


    console.log("Redirecting to " + res);
}

containsStrURL();
```

I have also tried `$('body').css(...);` but never worked.

There isn't anything in the HTML document to be covering the page, if that makes sense.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st: you have to use `$('body').css`

you can try

```
if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf("facebook") >= 0){
        $('body').css({
            'background-color': '#3E5B98'
         });
  }
```

Comment: I have implemented your code and unfortunately it doesn't work for me. On Chrome 47.0.2526.80.

Comment: @JoshMurray please try to console.log(res) and see what you will get

Comment: I cleared my browsers cache and tried again, it works now. Cheers

Comment: @JoshMurray glad it helped .. I will try .match and let you know what will going on .. Good Luck :)

Comment: @JoshMurray and this is for .match http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/t4ybdwts/